# Setup Objective function in PuLP with four dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, integer-programming

I am trying to build a scheduling optimization for employees working in different roles, days and shifts. I want to optimize the preference score given a schedule (the assignment matrix). However, I am having trouble with defining my objective function. I am using PuLP to setup my code, here is my setup:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp
from random import randint
from itertools import product

employees = range(11)
roles = range(5)
days = range(6)
shifts = range(3)
```

Variable X is the Assignment matrix which consists of 0s and 1s

```
X = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("X", product(employees, roles, days, shifts),
                          cat=pulp.LpBinary)
```

P is the preference score

```
for k in employees:
    for j in roles:
        for i in days: 
            for h in nr_shifts:
                P[(k, j, i,h)] = np.random.rand() - 0.5
```

The problem, maximizing the preference score:

```
scheduling_problem = pulp.LpProblem("Employee Scheduling", pulp.LpMaximize)
```

And the objective function (which is causing an error)

```
scheduling_problem += (pulp.lpSum(X[(k, j, i, h)] * P[(k, j, i, h)])
        for k in employees for j in roles for i in days for h in shifts
)
```

the error after running the objective function:

```
TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects
```

My objective is to sum the preference scores over the employees, roles, days and shifts and I thought that multiplying my preference scores with the assignments (simply 0s and 1s) would do the trick.

Any thoughts on this?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

That last statement is not valid Python: check the parentheses. You probably mean:

```
scheduling_problem += pulp.lpSum(X[(k, j, i, h)] * P[(k, j, i, h)]
        for k in employees for j in roles for i in days for h in shifts)
```